# Postgresql inserts values falsely

Tags: postgresql, gtfs

I want to add a denormalized table for some data of a gtfs-feed. For that I created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE denormalized_trips (
  stops_coords json NOT NULL,
  stops_object json NOT NULL,
  agency_key text NOT NULL,
  trip_id text NOT NULL,
  route_id text NOT NULL,
  service_id text NOT NULL,
  shape_id text,
  route_color text,
  route_long_name text,
  route_desc text,
  direction_id text
);

CREATE INDEX denormalized_trips_index ON denormalized_trips (agency_key, trip_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX denormalized_trips_index ON denormalized_trips (agency_key, route_id);
```

Now I want to transfer data from one table to the other via an insert statement. The statement is rather complex.

```
INSERT INTO denormalized_trips
SELECT
    trps.stops_coords,
    trps.stops_object,
    trps.trip_id,
    trps.service_id,
    trps.route_id,
    trps.direction_id,
    trps.agency_key,
    trps.shape_id,
    trps.route_color,
    trps.route_long_name,
    trps.route_desc
FROM (
SELECT
    array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(array[stop_lat, stop_lon])) AS stops_coords,
    array_to_json(ARRAY_AGG(array[
            stops.stop_id,
            CAST ( stop_times.stop_sequence AS TEXT ),
            stops.stop_name,
            stop_times.departure_time,
            CAST ( stop_times.departure_time_seconds AS TEXT ),
            stop_times.arrival_time,
            CAST ( stop_times.arrival_time_seconds AS TEXT )
        ])) AS stops_object,
    trips.trip_id,
    trips.service_id,
    trips.direction_id,
    trips.agency_key,
    trips.shape_id,
    routes.route_id,
    routes.route_color,
    routes.route_long_name,
    routes.route_desc
FROM gtfs_stop_times AS stop_times

INNER JOIN gtfs_trips AS trips
    ON trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id AND trips.agency_key = stop_times.agency_key

INNER JOIN gtfs_routes AS routes ON trips.agency_key = routes.agency_key AND routes.route_id = trips.route_id

INNER JOIN gtfs_stops AS stops
    ON stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
    AND stops.agency_key = stop_times.agency_key
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 0
      FROM denormalized_max_stop_sequence AS max
      WHERE max.agency_key = stop_times.agency_key
      AND max.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id
      AND max.trip_max = stop_times.stop_sequence
    )
GROUP BY
    trips.trip_id,
    trips.service_id,
    trips.direction_id,
    trips.agency_key,
    trips.shape_id,
    routes.route_id,
    routes.route_color,
    routes.route_long_name,
    routes.route_desc
) as trps
```

If I just run the inner select statement I will get the right results. They look something like this: (screenshot does not show all tables because it's too long)

[image: Correct results]

But if I execute the insert statement and display the content of the table i will get something like this:
[image: Wrong results]

As you may notice the contents are not inserted into the right columns of the table. The agency_key now has the values of the trip_id and the direction_id is now the service_id (and there are more tables that are messed up).

So my question is what am I doing wrong that my insert statement inserts the contents into the wrong columns of the newly created table?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres, by default, will insert your values in the order the columns are declared in the table; it has nothing to do with what your columns are named in the query.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

> If no list of column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the table in their declared order; or the first N column names, if there are only N columns supplied by the VALUES clause or query.

You can alter your insert to declare the order of the columns you're inserting, or you can change the order of your select to match the order of columns in the table.

Comment: thats it! I reordered my select statement and now it works. That gave me quite a headache. Thanks for the answer